# How to put 3 columns in another 3 columns in html

Tags: html, html-table

I'm having this trouble with table in html. I can't describe my problem with words, so I'm going to upload image here.
Just how to achieve this using tables in html.

This is what I tried, just create one row and in each one put three th's and in each one put another row, but it creates something weird actually.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Heading1
      <tr>
        <td>idk</td>
        <td>idk1</td>
        <td>idk2</td>
      </tr>
    </th>

    <th>Heading2
      <tr>
        <td>idk</td>
        <td>idk1</td>
        <td>idk2</td>
      </tr>
    </th>

    <th>Heading3
      <tr>
        <td>idk</td>
        <td>idk1</td>
        <td>idk2</td>
      </tr>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or this should theoretically work, but it doesn't

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Heading1</th>

    <th>Heading2</th>

    <th>Heading3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <td>idk</td>
      <td>idk1</td>
      <td>idk2</td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <td>idk</td>
      <td>idk1</td>
      <td>idk2</td>
    </td>
    <td>
      <td>idk</td>
      <td>idk1</td>
      <td>idk2</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: the table]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use two tables...

There are ways to make a header span the width of three columns.  Google search the term "css header span three columns", first result was:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_colspan.asp

Very easy to understand.

Once you do the above, your second table example will work if you remove the sub-td's.  ie change:

```
<td>
  <td>idk</td>
  <td>idk1</td>
  <td>idk2</td>
</td>
```

to just:

```
<td>idk</td>
<td>idk1</td>
<td>idk2</td>
```

if you want the nice color to the border like your paint, you can apply a different class to each td and set up 3 css definitions.

Comment: yeah, i forgot about the colspan, jesus, i did tables long time ago, but now im trying it with php and mysql. Btw. thx for help and i know css, but thx for help.